# The next [selection] for burnination

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The [selection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/selection) tag has 131 questions and 0 followers. Questions with this tag cover the entire scope of the site. The tag serves absolutely zero purpose and should be wiped from the face of Super User forever.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's too broad.

Comment: It does not _"cover the entire scope of the site"_ but under the criteria of "is someone _expert_ on this tag" it should be deleted.